# Can we host WCF service on different port if created in web application?

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I have a WCF service in the web application. Service and application are running fine. Web app address is localhost:53536 and service address is localhost:53536/Mobile/MobileService.svc. These are duplex services and I am consuming these service on the different application. Here is my configuration

```
<behaviors>

  <serviceBehaviors>

    <behavior name="" >

      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
  multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<bindings>
  <wsDualHttpBinding>
    <binding name="MobileServiceBinding" closeTimeout="00:00:05" openTimeout="00:00:05">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="5242880" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
    </binding>
  </wsDualHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>

  <service name="Asm.As.PerformanceMonitor.Web.Mobile.MobileService" >
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsDualHttpBinding"  bindingConfiguration="MobileServiceBinding" contract="Asm.As.PerformanceMonitor.Web.Mobile.IMobileService" />

  </service>

</services>
```

As you can see the address is empty. When I add address like http://localhost:1212
It's not working. An error comes refused to connect. Is there any way to host service on a different port or service has different address along with the application? Please note that service will be hosted with the web application.